# Where does the constant term $+1$ go when simplifying this integral in eq (2)?

Tags: integration, derivatives, expected-value, density-function

I've been looking at this breakdown that deals with taking the gradient of an expectation w.r.t the distribution the expectation is sampling from. On equation 2 is where I get stuck. **Where does the $+1$ on the RHS of eq (2) go?** I was/am expecting it to be: $\int{ (\log p_\theta(y) - \log q_\phi(x) +1 )  \nabla_{\phi}  q_\phi(x)  dz }$.

I've my answer and should add that both $p(x,z)$ and $q_\phi (z|x)$ are probabilities. By integrating over one (to get 1), then taking the gradient (to get 0), my $+1$ dissapears.

$$\begin{align} 
\nabla_{\phi} E_{q_\phi(z|x)} \left [ \log p(x, z) - \log q_\phi(z|x) \right] &= \nabla_{\phi} \int{\log p(x, z)  q_\phi(z|x) dz} -\nabla_{\phi} \int{q_\phi(z|x) \log q_\phi(z|x) dz } \tag{1}\\
&=\int{\log p(x, z) \nabla_{\phi} q_\phi(z|x) dz} - \int{(\log q_\phi(z|x) +1) \nabla_{\phi} 
q_\phi(z|x)  dz } \tag{2}\\
&= \int{ (\log p(x, z) - \log q_\phi(z|x) )  \nabla_{\phi}  q_\phi(z|x)  dz } \tag{3}
\end{align}$$

Comment: This is insanely dense in notations, maybe you could try to reduce a bit the verbosity in the question.

Comment: @PC1 Sure, I've removed a lot of clutter. For full reference [here's](https://ai.zjplab.com/2019/06/variational-autoencoders-1-motivation.html) a link, just ctrl+f "things become a bit more complicated"

Comment: I don't really follow what's going on, but the vanishing of that term seems to be explained by the "where we use the fact that" computation below what you've posted.

Comment: @Micah If the entire RHS falls off via that explanation, then shouldn't my equation 3 be: $=\int{\log{p(y)}\nabla_{\phi}q_\phi(x)dz}$ because it is terminating $-\log{q_\phi(x)}$?

Comment: What is the domain of integration? FTC can often be used to show the integral of a derivative is zero when the domain is the whole space.

Comment: @Ryan: That explanation doesn't purport to show that the entire RHS is zero, only that the term $\int \nabla_\phi q_\phi \, dz$ (i.e., exactly the term that involves the $+1$) is zero. Notice that there's no $\log q_\phi$ anywhere in it...

Comment: @Micah Oh I understand! I was wondering why the author went out of their way to factor out $\nabla_\phi q_\phi(z|x)$ from the RHS that I assumed it was a "right step". I see that you need to redistribute the term, then break apart the integral on the RHS to get that 0 which nullifies the +1 in question. Thank you.